# is it possible to re-direct stdout in a Bluemix python app?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

I've read that re-direction stdout to a local file in Bluemix, for a python app, maybe other apps, may not be supported.

I've recently tried the following in my Procfile and it seems to be working:

```
web: python server.py 1>server.out
```

Maybe I'm somehow lucky to have good success, or maybe the documentation I read is no longer accurate.

Comment: If it works for you, what is your question?

Comment: Redirecting stdout to a file is not a recommended practice for cloud-based applications.  The available disk space is limited and ephemeral.  Stdout for an app is available from the `cf logs {appname}` command or you can use a syslog drain.

Answer (score 5):

As you probably know, Bluemix is built on Cloud Foundry, and there are two important considerations to think about:

- **Local file system storage is short-lived**. When an application instance crashes or stops, the resources assigned to that instance are reclaimed by the platform including any local disk changes made since the app started. When the instance is restarted, the application will start with a new disk image. *Although your application can write local files while it is running, the files will disappear after the application restarts*.
- **Instances of the same application do not share a local file system**. Each application instance runs in its own isolated container. Thus *if your application needs the data in the files to persist across application restarts, or the data needs to be shared across all running instances of the application, the local file system should not be used.*

For this reason local file system ***should not be used***.

If you want more information on this topic please take a look at [Considerations for Designing and Running an Application in the Cloud](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html)